# How to shrink the image when asking quesions

Tags: support

I realized that I need to shrink the image when I asked this [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/69076/53576). I checked by clicking the edit. I could not find. How to shrink the image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is a button to shrink the image however, you can modify the url to use a smaller image for images hosted at imgur.com. Simply add a `m` for *medium* or `s` for *small* to the file name like so:

change `https://i.stack.imgur.com/agHbJ.png` to `https://i.stack.imgur.com/agHbJm.png`

You can see more on the thumbnails available [here](https://api.imgur.com/models/image#thumbs)

Comment: Beat me to it. But may I add the `t`, which comes in handy with more than 2 pics in a row? It stands for "tiny", and the resulting size is in between `m` and `s` (I feel `s` is pretty useless, as it doesn't seem to stand for "small", but "squared" ;)

Answer (score 1):

To enable better aspect ratios than that offered by Imgur's black magic offered in the previous answer, you could try using HTML tags like:

```
<img src="<image URL goes here>" width="<say 210>" height="<say 540>" alt="<alternate text in case the image does not display>" title="<some title text>"/>
```

I personally prefer this as the Imgur URL modifications mentioned above sometimes badly mess up aspect ratios of screenshots. This entails more effort than a modified link, but produces better results.

Comment: Sorry, @Firelord, corrected  the code